# is there a way to make localizable.strings case insensitive

Tags: iphone, localization

I'm using localization in my iPhone app.

I have almost 10 languages with long "string file" for each. What I noticed is that the strings inside the .string files are case sensitive which makes it a tedious job to track each file and each letter inside it especially that I am getting those files from another people who translate them for me.

So, is there any way to make those strings case insensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about if you set your keys for the localised strings to lowercase? So you don't have to worry about any uppercases.
I don't think its possible to make the strings explicitly case insensitive.

E.g.:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString(@"test", @"comment..."));
```

And in your Localizable.strings files for the corresponding language:

```
"test" = "Teststring English";

"test" = "Teststring Another Language";
```

Comment: its a good idea ,, but i thought there would be a generic methodology
cuz i have took many localizable files from translators and they played each of his side on the form of sentences ,...
i found myself at the end modifying them by hand :(
I will work with ur idea in later files :)